# Passing values from one form to another

Tags: php, javascript, database, web

I need some help.  I need some way of getting the information from this website:

https://npiregistry.cms.hhs.gov/NPPESRegistry/NPIRegistrySearch.do?subAction=reset&searchType=ind

and post it to my own.  What I'm wanting to do is have a doctor be able to put in his first and last name and NPI number and automatically post a handful of relevant fields like phone and address, without them having to put this information in themselves.

An example of what I'm trying to achieve would be:

https://provider.myhelo.com/enroll.php

In this website when a doctor puts in his information it asks how he wants to be contacted with his address and phone number both of which are populated based on the doctor's information he input.

I've looked at the PHP cURL method but I don't entirely understand it or know exactly if that's what I'm looking for.  I don't know javascript too well but I'm willing to learn.

Thank You

Comment: If you have no control other the cms.hhs.gov website, then there isn't anything you can do

Comment: Isn't the hhs page a search form? Shouldn't he just be able to either call their service or "scrape" their site?

Answer (score 0):

You can't get user-entered information from third-party site, unless that site is willing to provide this data to you.